# Is there a way to get Java to read a PNG as TYPE_INT_RGB / TYPE_INT_ARGB?

Tags: java, image, png, javax.imageio

When I read a PNG image in Java using `javax.imageio.ImageIO.read()`, the resulting `BufferedImage` is of `TYPE_3BYTE_BGR` or `TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR` depending on transparency.

I'm processing very large images (64+ megapixels), and need them in `TYPE_INT_RGB` / `TYPE_INT_ARGB` format, which requires an expensive and very-large-chunk-of-memory hogging repainting of the image onto a new image in the correct format, which is causing OOMs.

It would be much better if I could somehow persuade `ImageIO` to read the image in the desired format from the get-go - is there any way of doing that? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to read into a predefined type of `BufferedImage`, given that the type is supported by and compatible with the reader plugin. Most often the `TYPE_#BYTE_*` types are compatible with the `TYPE_INT_*` types, and this is the case for the standard `PNGImageReader`.

To make it work, you need access to the `ImageReader` directly, and use the `read` method that takes an `ImageReadParam` to control the type of image. It's possible to read into a pre-allocated image by using the `ImageReadParam.setDestination(..)` method, or to just specify the type of image and let the reader plugin allocate it for you by using `ImageReadParam.setDestinationType(..)` like I will show below.

Here's a short stand-alone code sample that shows how to read into a specific image type:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File input = new File(args[0]);

    try (ImageInputStream stream = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(input)) {
        // Find a suitable reader
        Iterator<ImageReader> readers = ImageIO.getImageReaders(stream);
        if (!readers.hasNext()) {
            throw new IIOException("No reader for " + input);
        }

        ImageReader reader = readers.next();
        try {
            reader.setInput(stream);

            // Query the reader for types and select the best match
            ImageTypeSpecifier intPackedType = getIntPackedType(reader);
            System.out.println("intPackedType = " + intPackedType);

            // Pass the type to the reader using read param
            ImageReadParam param = reader.getDefaultReadParam();
            param.setDestinationType(intPackedType);

            // Finally read the image
            BufferedImage image = reader.read(0, param);
            System.out.println("image = " + image);
        }
        finally {
            reader.dispose();
        }
    }
}

private static ImageTypeSpecifier getIntPackedType(ImageReader reader) throws IOException {
    Iterator<ImageTypeSpecifier> types = reader.getImageTypes(0);

    while (types.hasNext()) {
        ImageTypeSpecifier spec = types.next();

        switch (spec.getBufferedImageType()) {
            case BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB:
            case BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB:
                return spec;
            default:
                // continue searching
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Sample output from one of my runs using a PNG as input:

```
intPackedType = javax.imageio.ImageTypeSpecifier$Packed@707084ba
image = BufferedImage@45ff54e6: type = 2 DirectColorModel: rmask=ff0000 gmask=ff00 bmask=ff amask=ff000000 IntegerInterleavedRaster: width = 100 height = 100 #Bands = 4 xOff = 0 yOff = 0 dataOffset[0] 0
```

Where `type = 2` means `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB`.

Comment: Thanks Harald! For any future readers who may want to use the same method to also read JPEGs: be aware of https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6357444 - you have to use `param.setDestination(intPackedType.createBufferedImage(w, h))`, see the workaround in that link for the details & be sure to null-check `intPackedType` of course.

Comment: The bug is listed as fixed, but that seems to not actually be the case as of Java 1.8.0_241 on win10. The workaround appears to work regardless.

Comment: Also, it can be quite a bit slower to read to `TYPE_INT_(A)RGB` vs whatever the default is. For a large example JPEG image it takes ~1x to read it to the default format, ~0.1x to redraw it to `TYPE_INT_ARGB`, but ~1.5x to read it directly into `TYPE_INT_(A)RGB`. About the same for PNGs.